# Change some elements of an array using a mask in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia

I want to perform an operation on only some members of an array in Julia. New to the language and not sure what to do. This is my little toy test:

```
myarray = ones(5)
mymask = [true; false; false; false; true;]
myarray = myarray[mymask] * 2
```

The third line is not right, the output is:

```
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
 2.0
 2.0
```

What I want to get is:

```
5-element Array{Float64,1}:
 2.0
 1.0
 1.0
 1.0
 2.0
```

I'm especially interested in the most efficient way to do this, because the actual arrays I am working with may be quite large. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `myarray[mask]` as a target on the left hand side, and then have an assignment or an operation on the right.  For example:

```
julia> myarray[mymask] = 2;

julia> myarray[~mymask] *= 3;

julia> myarray
5-element Array{Float64,1}:
 2.0
 3.0
 3.0
 3.0
 2.0
```

Right now, with `myarray = myarray[mymask] * 2`, you're setting `myarray` to an array of the resulting modified terms.

Comment: Oh OK. So what I want to do in this example is `myarray[mymask] = myarray[mymask] * 2`. Thanks!

Comment: @BenS.: you don't need to repeat `myarray[mymask]`, that's why I gave the `*= 3` example.

Answer (score 2):

Complementing DSM's answer, note that a `BitArray` is probably more memory efficient for your purposes than an array of `Bool` components:

```
p = 2000
x = Array{Bool,1}(p) # e.g. [true; false; ...; true]
y = trues(p)         # BitArray
```

Compare the sizes:

```
julia> sizeof(x)
2000

julia> sizeof(y)
256
```

You could fill `y` with `false`s as needed, e.g. `y[1] = false`, to create your desired bitmask.